# ZONE_NORMAL association with kernel/user-pages

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, arm, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

[image]

Above is presented a case where I have only 512 MB of physical memory. What I have read up so far, is that ZONE_NORMAL is mapped to the kernel virtual address space as shown. Essentially I have a 512 MB physical memory, out of which 496 MB worth of ZONE_NORMAL is mapped to the kernel virtual space. Based on this understanding, following are my question:

- Does, ZONE_NORMAL consists of **only** kernel space pages ?
- If ZONE_NORMAL consists only of kernel pages and is mapped **completely** to the kernel space virtual address range, where do the user space pages get located ?? There does not seem to be any room for user space pages in physical memory.

I am totally mixed up of the case where the physical memory is less than 4GB as shown in this case that I have put forth. Have I "missed" out on the ZONE_HIGHMEM here ? How does it get determined, how much of the physical memory goes to ZONE_NORMAL and how much goes to ZONE_HIGHMEM ?

Would really appreciate if someone can throw light on this.

Answer (score 4):

Does, ZONE_NORMAL consists of only kernel space pages ?

=== NO.

ZONE_NORMAL means it is linearly mapped into the physical memory. The offset between the virtual address and the corresponding physical address is a constant value (normally, it is 0xc000,0000). For example, if the virtual address is 0xc123,0000, then its physical address is 0x0123,0000.

Pages in ZONE_NORMAL can be used either by the kernel or the user level processes, as long as they are not conflict with each other.

ZONE_HIGHMEM only exist when the physical memory is larger than 896MB.

Comment: Note the question and the answer is about 32 bit architecture. In new 64 bit world, the normal zone is much bigger and probably you don't need ZONE_HIGHMEM.

Comment: I don't think your statement "ZONE_NORMAL means it is linearly mapped into the physical memory" is true.